# how to make my html text background transparent without makeing the text transparent

Tags: css

how can i make my html text transparent

the thing is im trying to make a css and html nav bar
evetything is beautiful and blurred background with
backdrop-filter: blur(8px);     in the css file but in html when i come to write the text
the text part:

and my text is coming like this:
[the thing and the brobem with texts not haveing a blured background 1]
and here is my css code for the nav bar:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;


}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 25px 35px;
    font-family: "Arial Rounded MT",sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

header{
    height:70px;
    background:url("");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;

}

ul{
    list-style:none;
}

li{
    display:inline-block;
}

li a {
   margin-left:40px;
}

nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-decoration:none
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a herf="#LELKASA">
        LELKASA
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a herf="#Home">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a herf="#SiteMap">SiteMap</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a herf="#Download Center">Download Center</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a herf="#About">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are there some images of the problem that could help us understand a bit more?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ePamJ75 the text has a black background its the background im useing for my html
i need it to not to have that text with a background insted i want the text background to have a blur

Answer (score 0):

If you want text to have a background:

```
nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: rgb(255,255,255,0.1);
}
```

First three values are for r,g,b ranging from 0 to 255. If I give all 255, it will be closer to white and if I give all 0 it will be closer to black. Last property will range from 0 to 1 deciding the transparency.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to blur the nav links you can set `opacity` to them. I have added `opacity: 0.7` to the nav links. When the mouse is hovered on each of them, opacity becomes 1. You can blur them more by setting a lower opacity value to them.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;


}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 25px 35px;
    font-family: "Arial Rounded MT",sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
}

header{
    height:70px;
    background:url("");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;

}

ul{
    list-style:none;
}

li{
    display:inline-block;
}

li a {
   margin-left:40px;
}

nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
nav a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a herf="#LELKASA">
        LELKASA
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a herf="#Home">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a herf="#SiteMap">SiteMap</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a herf="#Download Center">Download Center</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a herf="#About">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```